# Receive warning "Image must be used from main thread only"

Tags: swift, firebase, uiimage

I tried to fetch a image from Firebase by using the code below and I receive a "!" saying: "UIImageView.image must be used from main thread only". Could anyone tell me what the issue is?

```
var post: Post? {
didSet {
 showImage()
}
}

func showImage() {

    BANNER_REF.child("Ev5").child("imageUrl").observeSingleEvent(of: .value, with: { snapshot in
        if let url = snapshot.value as? String {
            URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: URL(string: url)!) { data, response, error in
                print(snapshot)
                if error == nil {
                    let image = UIImage(data: data!)
                    self.bannerAdImageView.image = image
                }
                }.resume()
        }
    })
}
```

Comment: The issue is exactly what it says. You are saying `self.bannerAdImageView.image = image` on a background thread. That is illegal.

Answer (score 1):

You are trying to do UI work (setting the image) on a thread other than the main thread which is not allowed. You should set it on the main thread like this

```swift
DispatchQueue.main.async {
    let image = UIImage(data: data!)
    self.bannerAdImageView.image = image
}
```

See https://developer.apple.com/documentation/code_diagnostics/main_thread_checker

Comment: Personally, I’d go ahead and do the `let image = ...` on that background queue and only dispatch the update of the `bannerAdImageView.image` to the main queue. No reason to block your UI in a potentially slow process of converting the `data` to a `UIImage`...